# expl3: \cs_generate_variant broke with the last update: undefined control sequence \::T

Tags: expansion, expl3

The last expl3 update broke my "continue" detection for the index. Here is a MWE:
(**EDIT**: I realized it is possible to reduce it even further)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { xxTF }

\def\ifevenmarkcontd#1{
    \tl_if_eq:xxTF { me } { you }
    {
    }
    {
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ifevenmarkcontd{anything}
\end{document}
```

When running it the error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \::T
                \::F
l.19

?
```

If I use `\tl_if_eq:nnTF` then it compiles. But I need to expand the arguments, and it did work before the last update. How can I fix this now? What is the reason?

Comment: I actually had the same error a while back.  I assumed I wasn't allowed to define a variant with the following TF because I hadn't had a working version previously.

Comment: This is a bug report rather than a question; as such, it would be more appropriate on the LaTeX-L mailing list (see http://www.latex-project.org/code.html) than here.  See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2622/2966 for discussion of this policy.

Comment: oh, sorry. I will send an email as well then.

Comment: I forget how I resolved the issue.  At worst you can probably use \tl_set:Nx to expand the the arguments and then pass the resulting tl's to \tl_if_eq:NNTF.

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/100

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the point tohecz makes, you don't really need the `TF` here, which is probably why we've not picked this up in testing. I would do simple

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_eq:nnTF { xx }
```

Comment: Aha, that does work indeed, thanks! It's not documented though ;)

Comment: Agreed, and commented that on the issue tracker.  I'll look at it soonish.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a bug in LaTeX3 and as such, it should be reported using the way explained by *J. C. Salomon* in the comments.